# Computer algebra programs that can solve polynomial systems on algebraically closed fields besides MAGMA

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, computer-algebra, groebner-bases, global-fields

I was wondering which computer algebra programs out there can solve polynomial systems on the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ analytically and efficiently.
So far, I only found MAGMA with its `AlgebraicClosure()` functionality, where field extensions are added to $\mathbb{Q}$ whenever necessary during calculations.
But are there any programs besides MAGMA, preferably open-source? Scrolling through the documentations of GAP, OSCAR, Singular etc. hasn't really helped.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I suppose you are talking about the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, as opposed to other fields (e.g., of characteristic $p>0$ or function fields). GAP definitely cannot do this: it can only handle abelian (viꝫ., cyclotomic) extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ (at least the GAP core — maybe some packages do better). [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/), on the other hand, implements exact algebraic numbers and arbitrary number fields. But whether it can “solve polynomial systems” depend on exactly what you mean by that.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ (question edited for more clarity). By polynomial systems I mean equation systems consisting of polynomials of arbitrary degree. MAGMA solves such systems by computing the variety of a Groebner basis. MAGMA's advantage is its efficient implementation but also its ability to carry out such calculations on the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm answering the question, but Maple's Groebner package says "calculations of Groebner bases and related operations for ideals in (commutative) polynomial rings.  The Groebner package is actually much more general and can handle polynomials in skew polynomial rings and modules over (commutative or skew) polynomial rings" and "supports transcendental and algebraic extensions of the field of rational numbers and finite fields. This includes algebraic number fields."

Comment: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/qqbar.html has some examples of what AA$=\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ is in sage.

Comment: SymPy is a good package that can do a bunch of this stuff. [Here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#systems-of-polynomial-equations) is a good place to start. Sympy underlies much of the symbolic math in Sage, and it has the merit of working smoothly with a standard Python interpreter.

Comment: I actually have very bad experiences with SymPy solvers in terms of efficiency and I also encountered examples, where SymPy was not able to find all possible solutions.

Comment: @ArminJR Yes, SymPy does have some issues, and its usage is a bit idiosyncratic, but I am optimistic as they continue to improve it